# rxjs, how to merge several requests, one serial request in parallel requests, and get one result

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs6

for example,
I have 2 API service, returning type is Observable.

```
function add(row) {
    let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2000);
    let k = row + 1;
    return timer(r).pipe(mapTo(k));
}

function mutiple(row) {
    let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2000);
    let k = row * 10;
    return timer(r).pipe(mapTo(k));
}
```

there is an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, I use the two function as follow:

```
from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).pipe(
        mergeMap((row) => {
            return add(row);
        }),
        mergeMap((row) => {
            return mutiple(row);
        }),
        toArray()
    ).subscribe((_) => {
        console.log("sub", _);
    });
```

the result is

```
sub [ 50, 20, 60, 40, 30 ]
```

the answer is that I want.

however, I don't know the source of the element of the array,
I hope the result is

```
[ [4, 50], [1, 20], [5, 60], [3, 40], [2, 30] ]
```

or

```
[
  { sourceData: 4, result: 50 },
  { sourceData: 1, result: 20 },
  ...
]
```

if I use contactMap to keep the sequence, the program will execute one by one,
I don't care the sequence, I just wanna know how to connect the source and the result.

Thank you so much~

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way?

```js
  from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).pipe(
    mergeMap((row) => {
      const index$ = of(row);
      return forkJoin([index$, add(row)]);
    }),
    mergeMap(([index, row]) => {
      return forkJoin([of(index), mutiple(row)]);
    }),
    toArray()
  ).subscribe((_) => {
    console.log("sub", _);
  });
```

or

```js
  const handler = v => {
    return of(v).pipe(
      mergeMap((row) => {
        return add(row);
      }),
      mergeMap((row) => {
        return mutiple(row);
      }),
    )
  }

  from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).pipe(
    mergeMap(row => forkJoin([of(row), handler(row)])),
    toArray()
  ).subscribe((_) => {
    console.log("sub", _);
  });
```